# Calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate
>
> $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx$

I'd like to exchange the integral with the serie in order to do the calculus.

I'm not sure under which conditions I can do the following (and why is permitted theoretically):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx$ = $ \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}dx$

Because then, knowing that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1} x^{n+1} = ln(1+x)$ solving the integral becomes simpler.

Comment: See that $$\frac{x^{n + 1}}{x + 1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{x + 1} + (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n - 1}{\cos{(k \pi)} \cdot x^{k + 1}}$$. Also, see that this is alternating for the main summation ($\sum^{\infty}_{n = 0}{\dots}$). What do you think will happen to most terms in the sequence?

Comment: I am unable to edit my previous comment; all the $"n"$ should be $"n+1"$ and there should be a $"+"$ operator in between $(-1)^n$ and the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition: (Fubini's theorem):

If $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1|f_n(x)|\;dx < \infty,$$ then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 f_n(x) \;dx =  \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\;dx.$$
It is applicable in this case.

---

Other possible conditions: monotone convergence, dominated convergence, etc. I leave to others to check.

---

All of the above are from the Lebesgue theory of integration.  The condition in the Riemann theory of integration involves uniform convergence.  This, also, is applicable here.

Comment: So if $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly then the equivalence is valid?

Comment: No.  If $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly then the conclusion is valid.  Here, you would use the Weierstrass M test.